# Stuck command in Powershell but not in Cmd.exe

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

i'm facing a problem, my powershell script have a very strange comportement.

There is a little piece of a big script :

```
Write-Host "Installation in progress..." 
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ThrottleLimit 64 -ScriptBlock {.\XenDesktopServerSetup.exe /QUIET /CONFIGURE_FIREWALL /components $using:componentparam /nosql }
Write-Host "Installation completed"
```

Sometimes even if the execution of `XenDesktopServerSetup.exe` is finished my script doesn't pass to the next command     `Write-Host "Installation completed"` 
I need to click somewhere in the shell or break the script with CTRL+C to see the end of my script;

I tried to change `ThrottleLimit`, but i doesn't have effect.

I'm using Powershell V4.0.

There is only one server in $Session.

**EDIT :**
I tried this command **directly on my server**, i opened a PS Shell and executed :

```
.\XenDesktopServerSetup.exe /QUIET /CONFIGURE_FIREWALL /components CONTROLLER /nosql
```

**I had the same problem !**

But when i tried the same command in Cmd.exe, it works perfectly and everytime !

How can i execute this command in Cmd.exe ? I want something like this :

```
Write-Host "Installation in progress..." 
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ThrottleLimit 64 -ScriptBlock {Cmd.exe .\XenDesktopServerSetup.exe /QUIET /CONFIGURE_FIREWALL /components $using:componentparam /nosql }
Write-Host "Installation completed"
```

This shows us that there is a difference between cmd.exe and powershell in how PS make the call of .exe file, but I don't understand at all why it works in cmd.exe but not in powershell

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Are you sure *all* of the remote servers are done?  You could use the `-AsJob` parameter and then periodically inspect the state of each job using `Get-Job`.  Retrieve output with `Receive-Job`. You can even wait for all to finish *with* a timeout using `Wait-Job $jobs -Timeout 120`.

Comment: How many servers are there in the $Session?

Comment: @MikeShepard i updated my answer, there is only 1 server.

Comment: @KeithHill Thanks for your suggestion, i updated my answer, it seems better

Comment: ThrottleLimit controls how many concurrent connections are made to the computers involved in the session (or listed in ComputerName).  With only one computer, increasing the ThrottleLimit wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: @AdeelASIF OK, I've converted my comment to an answer.

Comment: Here's a great resource on running .exe in Powershell

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

Comment: Running exe in Powershell with more than 1 argument, I used example #10 (Stop-Parsing symbol --%)

Comment: @BrianWochele None of these parameters `/QUIET /CONFIGURE_FIREWALL /components CONTROLLER /nosql` should cause a problem with PowerShell parameter parsing.  Now if the OP is installing multiple components and specifying those comps literllay e.g. `/components CONTROLLER,WEBACCESS` then yeah, they would need to use `--%`.  But if the components are specified in a variable e.g. $using:componentparam then --% is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i resolved it, I tested it a lot and i don't have any issue :

```
Write-Host "Installation in progress..." 
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {$Components = $using:componentparam}
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression "cmd /C '$IsoLetter\x64\XenDesktop Setup\XenDesktopServerSetup.exe' /QUIET /CONFIGURE_FIREWALL /components $Components /nosql" }
Write-Host "Installation completed"
```

What do you think? I think the problem is in the .exe file.. there is something wrong with.

But finally i solved it by using `Invoke-expression` and `cmd /C`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure all of the remote servers are done? You could use the -AsJob parameter and then periodically inspect the state of each job using Get-Job. Retrieve output with Receive-Job. You can even wait for all to finish with a timeout using Wait-Job $jobs -Timeout 120